# wait3 (waitpid alias) returns -1 with errno set to ECHILD when it should not

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, zombie-process, waitpid

Context is this [Redis issue](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2897). We have a `wait3()` call that waits for the AOF rewriting child to create the new AOF version on disk. When the child is done, the parent is notified via `wait3()` in order to substitute the old AOF with the new one.

However in the context of the above issue the user notified us about a bug. I modified a bit the implementation of Redis 3.0 in order to clearly log when `wait3()` returned -1 instead of crashing because of this unexpected condition. So this is what happens apparently:

1. `wait3()` is called when we have pending children to wait for.
2. the `SIGCHLD` should be set to `SIG_DFL`, there is no code setting this signal at all in Redis, so it's the default behavior.
3. When the first AOF rewrite happens, `wait3()` successfully works as expected.
4. Starting from the second AOF rewrite (the second child created), `wait3()` starts to return -1.

AFAIK it is not possible in the current code that we call `wait3()` while there are no pending children, since when the AOF child is created, we set `server.aof_child_pid` to the value of the pid, and we reset it only after a successful `wait3()` call.

So `wait3()` should have no reason to fail with -1 and `ECHILD`, but it does, so probably the zombie child is not created for some unexpected reason.

**Hypothesis 1**: It is possible that Linux during certain odd conditions will discard the zombie child, for example because of memory pressure? Does not look reasonable since the zombie has just metadata attached to it but who knows.

Note that we call `wait3()` with `WNOHANG`. And given that `SIGCHLD` is set to `SIG_DFL` by default, the only condition that should lead to failing and returning -1 and `ECHLD` should be no zombie available to report the information.

**Hypothesis 2**: Other thing that could happen but there is no explanation if it happens, is that after the first child dies, the `SIGCHLD` handler is set to `SIG_IGN`, causing `wait3()` to return -1 and `ECHLD`.

**Hypothesis 3**: Is there some way to remove the zombie children externally? Maybe this user has some kind of script that removes zombie processes in the background so that then the information is no longer available for `wait3()`? To my knowledge it should *never be possible* to remove the zombie if the parent does not wait for it (with `waitpid` or handling the signal) and if the `SIGCHLD` is not ignored, but maybe there is some Linux specific way.

**Hypothesis 4**: There is actually some bug in the Redis code so that we successfully `wait3()` the child the first time without correctly resetting the state, and later we call `wait3()` again and again but there are no longer zombies, so it returns -1. Analyzing the code it looks impossible, but maybe I'm wrong.

Another important thing: *we never observed this in the past*. Only happens in this specific Linux system apparently.

**UPDATE**: Yossi Gottlieb proposed that the `SIGCHLD` is received by another thread in the Redis process for some reason (does not happen normally, only on this system). We already mask `SIGALRM` in `bio.c` threads, perhaps we could try masking `SIGCHLD` from I/O threads as well.

## Appendix: selected parts of Redis code

Where wait3() is called:

```
/* Check if a background saving or AOF rewrite in progress terminated. */
if (server.rdb_child_pid != -1 || server.aof_child_pid != -1) {
    int statloc;
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = wait3(&statloc,WNOHANG,NULL)) != 0) {
        int exitcode = WEXITSTATUS(statloc);
        int bysignal = 0;

        if (WIFSIGNALED(statloc)) bysignal = WTERMSIG(statloc);

        if (pid == -1) {
            redisLog(LOG_WARNING,"wait3() returned an error: %s. "
                "rdb_child_pid = %d, aof_child_pid = %d",
                strerror(errno),
                (int) server.rdb_child_pid,
                (int) server.aof_child_pid);
        } else if (pid == server.rdb_child_pid) {
            backgroundSaveDoneHandler(exitcode,bysignal);
        } else if (pid == server.aof_child_pid) {
            backgroundRewriteDoneHandler(exitcode,bysignal);
        } else {
            redisLog(REDIS_WARNING,
                "Warning, detected child with unmatched pid: %ld",
                (long)pid);
        }
        updateDictResizePolicy();
    }
} else {
```

Selected parts of `backgroundRewriteDoneHandler`:

```
void backgroundRewriteDoneHandler(int exitcode, int bysignal) {
    if (!bysignal && exitcode == 0) {
        int newfd, oldfd;
        char tmpfile[256];
        long long now = ustime();
        mstime_t latency;

        redisLog(REDIS_NOTICE,
            "Background AOF rewrite terminated with success");

        ... more code to handle the rewrite, never calls return ...

    } else if (!bysignal && exitcode != 0) {
        server.aof_lastbgrewrite_status = REDIS_ERR;

        redisLog(REDIS_WARNING,
            "Background AOF rewrite terminated with error");
    } else {
        server.aof_lastbgrewrite_status = REDIS_ERR;

        redisLog(REDIS_WARNING,
            "Background AOF rewrite terminated by signal %d", bysignal);
    }

cleanup:
    aofClosePipes();
    aofRewriteBufferReset();
    aofRemoveTempFile(server.aof_child_pid);
    server.aof_child_pid = -1;
    server.aof_rewrite_time_last = time(NULL)-server.aof_rewrite_time_start;
    server.aof_rewrite_time_start = -1;
    /* Schedule a new rewrite if we are waiting for it to switch the AOF ON. */
    if (server.aof_state == REDIS_AOF_WAIT_REWRITE)
        server.aof_rewrite_scheduled = 1;
}
```

As you can see all the code paths must execute the `cleanup` code that reset `server.aof_child_pid` to -1.

## Errors logged by Redis during the issue

> 21353:C 29 Nov 04:00:29.957 * AOF rewrite: 8 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
>
> 27848:M 29 Nov 04:00:30.133 ^@ wait3() returned an error: No child processes. rdb_child_pid = -1, aof_child_pid = 21353

As you can see `aof_child_pid` is not -1.

Comment: To me this sounds as if you are testing to fast, to early, the child simply did not end yet.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to elaborate on how you make sure this: "*wait3() is called when we have pending children to wait for.*" really is the case, as it obviously isn't. I have to admit, I do not know the Redis code, but which other mechanics would you use to synchronize processes regarding their live time, but using calls to `wait*()`? I'd say you are facing a race.

Comment: @alk: About the "testing too fast" comment, wait3 should return 0 if the child is still working not -1, as I used WNOHANG as specified.

About your second comment, you can find the relevant code snippet in the appendix where it is highlighted where wait3 is called, how the work it does is handled by the function backgroundRewriteDoneHandler(), and how this function can only result, AFAIK, into setting aof_child_pid to -1.

Comment: Perhaps the moment you call `wait3()` the child did not even started yet (completely)?

Comment: Not possible because of fork() semantics. The parent is notified with the child pid when fork() returns, and the child process exists from now on. However if you check the original issue, there is a continuous look of wait3() calls so even in the future it never returns something different.

Comment: For debugging: Handle `pid==-1`/`ECHLD` the same as `pid==0` and log whether `wait3()` finds the process in question later.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the set up correctly: Do you observer the described behaviour *also* when explicitly setting `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);`?

Comment: Per `man 7 signal` the default for `SIGCHLD` is to be ignored.

Comment: Also to have more portable code (and probably less such issues as you are observing) you want to replace `signal()` by `sigaction()`.

Comment: SIGCHLD by default is set to SIG_DFL, just the documentation is a bit confusing. Also note that this works in all the Redis installations out there *but* in this system explicitly and reproducibly. The default action for SIGCHLD is to ignore the signal in the sense no signal hander is called, but zombie processes will queue waiting for waitpid() to receive their status. Btw if you check at the end of the Redis issue at Github, it was suggested for the user to explicitly set the signal to SIG_DFL and retry. However note that the *first* time the child exists, waitpid() works.

Comment: @antirez The older unix signal did reset the signal handler to default (`SIG_DFL`) *after* the first handling of a signal. So it's possible that hypothesis 2 to happen. Simply replace `signal()` call with `sigaction()` (which doesn't reset to SIG_DFL) to see if this is true.

Comment: @Blue Moon: yep I though to this, but it's a recent Linux system, Ubuntu 12.04, and the paradox is, SIG_DFL is what we want, so that is almost impossible to be the cause. Hypothesis two is that, incredibly, it would be reset to SIG_IGN instead of SIG_DFL. Anyway se use sigaction() in the rest of the code but for those two signals, so indeed, it's better to switch everything to sigaction() for clearness, but in this specific matter should not be related.

Comment: @antirez with regards to your updates about threads and masking signals, it might help to mask all signals on all but the thread(s) that you're okay to receive signals on. Not really related, but for example, in PulseAudio, in the client library, we explicitly mask receiving any signals at all since we want no interruptions in a potentially real-time I/O thread.

Comment: @antirez, since apparently you know the pid of the child you are waiting for, and you want to wait specifically for that particular child, it seems it would be wiser to use `wait4()` than `wait3()`.  I doubt that will fix the issue you asked about, but it may save you grief later.

Comment: @antirez, on the other hand, is there any chance that another thread collects the expected child first?

Comment: In any event, if indeed the behavior can be reproduced only in a specific system, then that strongly suggests that some unusual characteristic of that system is influencing it.  Perhaps it is the system that is broken, rather than Redis.  Perhaps a buggy kernel module or a misconfigured custom kernel is in play.

Comment: Redis has another wait3() call in  sentinelCollectTerminatedScripts(), can we be certain this doesn't eat up the processes identified by `rdb_child_pid /server.aof_child_pid` in this case ?

Comment: Building on the comment by @nos, `stopAppendOnly` in `aof.c` also kills and wait3s, specifically for the process in question.  Can you be sure some other code hasn't already won the race to reap the child?  It may be a red herring, but in your bug report the errors all happen very near five minute boundaries — perhaps cron or some other timed maintenance job is causing the unexpected reap?

Comment: I would start by running the code behind `strace(1)`, make sure to use `-e` so that you only see the calls to `wait3(2)`. This will tell you if the code is actually trying to reap the same child more than once or if it's something external that is wiping the zombie (misconfigured or buggy kernel, or other weird scripts running on that user's machine).

Comment: Also, were you able to reproduce this issue? Maybe installing the same kernel image in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 6):

TLDR: you are currently relying on unspecified behaviour of `signal`(2); use `sigaction` (carefully) instead.

Firstly, `SIGCHLD` is strange. From the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) for `sigaction`;

> POSIX.1-1990 disallowed setting the action for `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN`.  POSIX.1-2001 allows this  possibility, so that ignoring `SIGCHLD` can be used to prevent the creation of zombies (see `wait`(2)).  Nevertheless, the historical BSD and System V behaviors for ignoring `SIGCHLD` differ, so that  the  only completely  portable  method  of ensuring that terminated children do not become zombies is to catch the `SIGCHLD` signal and perform a `wait`(2) or similar.

And here's the bit from `wait`(2)'s [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait):

> POSIX.1-2001 specifies that if the disposition of `SIGCHLD` is set to `SIG_IGN` or the `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag is set for `SIGCHLD` (see `sigaction`(2)), then children that terminate do not become zombies and a call to `wait()`  or `waitpid()` will block until all children have terminated, and then fail with errno set to `ECHILD`.  (The original POSIX standard left the behavior of setting `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN` unspecified.   Note that even though the default disposition of `SIGCHLD` is "ignore", explicitly setting the disposition to `SIG_IGN` results in different treatment of zombie process children.)  Linux  2.6  conforms  to  this  specification.  However, Linux 2.4 (and earlier) does not: if a `wait()` or `waitpid()` call is made while `SIGCHLD` is being ignored, the call behaves just as though `SIGCHLD` were not  being ignored,  that  is,  the call blocks until the next child terminates and then returns the process ID       and status of that child.

Note the effect of that is that if the signal's handling behaves like `SIG_IGN` is set, then (under Linux 2.6+) you will see the behaviour you are seeing - i.e. `wait()` will return `-1` and `ECHLD` because the child will have been automatically reaped.

Secondly, signal handling with `pthreads` (which I think you are using here) is notoriously hard. The way it's meant to work (as I'm sure you know) is that process directed signals get sent to an arbitrary thread within the process that has the signal unmasked. But whilst threads have their own signal mask, there is a process wide action handler.

Putting these two things together, I think you are running across a problem I've run across before. I have had problems getting `SIGCHLD` handling to work with `signal()` (which is fair enough as that was deprecated prior to pthreads), which were fixed by moving to `sigaction` and carefully setting per thread signal masks. My conclusion at the time was that the C library was emulating (with `sigaction`) what I was telling it to do with `signal()`, but was getting tripped up by `pthreads`.

Note that you are currently relying on *unspecified behaviour*. From the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) of `signal(2)`:

> **The effects of `signal()` in a multithreaded process are unspecified.**

Here's what I recommend you do:

1. Move to `sigaction()` and `pthread_sigmask()`. Explicitly set the handling of all the signals you care about (even if you think that's the current default), even when setting them to `SIG_IGN` or `SIG_DFL`. I block signals whilst I do this (possibly overabundance of caution but I copied the example from somewhere).

Here's what I am doing (roughly):

```
sigset_t set;
struct sigaction sa;

/* block all signals */
sigfillset (&set);
pthread_sigmask (SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

/* Set up the structure to specify the new action. */
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (struct sigaction));
sa.sa_handler = handlesignal;        /* signal handler for INT, TERM, HUP, USR1, USR2 */
sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction (SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
sigaction (SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
sigaction (SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
sigaction (SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
sigaction (SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);

sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction (SIGPIPE, &sa, NULL);     /* I don't care about SIGPIPE */

sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction (SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);     /* I want SIGCHLD to be handled by SIG_DFL */

pthread_sigmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
```

2. Where possible set all your signal handlers and masks etc. prior to any `pthread` operations. Where possible do not change signal handlers and masks (you might need to do this prior to and subsequent to `fork()` calls).
3. If you need to a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` (rather than relying on `SIG_DFL`), if possible let it be received by any thread, and use the self-pipe method or similar to alert the main program.
4. If you must have threads that do/don't handle certain signals, try to restrict yourself to `pthread_sigmask` in the relevant thread rather than `sig*` calls.
5. Just in case you run headlong into the next issue I ran into, ensure that after you have `fork()`'d, you set up again the signal handling from scratch (in the child) rather than relying on whatever you might inherit from the the parent process. If there's one thing worse than signals mixed with pthread, it's signals mixed with pthread with `fork()`.

Note I cannot explain exactly entirely *why* change (1) works, but it has fixed what looks like a very similar issue for me and was after all relying on something that was 'unspecified' previously. It's closest to your 'hypothesis 2' but I think it is really incomplete emulation of legacy signal functions (specifically emulating the previously racy behaviour of `signal()` which is what caused it to be replaced by `sigaction()` in the first place - but this is just a guess).

Incidentally, I suggest you use `wait4()` or (as you aren't using `rusage`) `waitpid()` rather than `wait3()`, so you can specify a specific PID to wait for. If you have something else that generates children (I've had a library do it), you may end up waiting for the wrong thing. That said, I don't think that's what's happening here.

Comment: Not germane, I think.  Both the OP and a grep of the sources suggest that SIGCHLD's disposition is never set in the code.  Neither is it masked (not that that would matter here).  The symptoms, further, suggest that SIG_IGN could not be inherited, since wait3 works normally at least once.

Comment: I would still suggest setting it up properly with `sigaction`. It working the first time doesn't surprise me; it worked unreliably for me, and some semantics for an emulated signal require the signal handling be reset in the handler. If it has no effect then it's *still* the right way to set up signal handling.

Comment: Wise advice but again not applicable here.  It isn't "set up" at all — there are no calls to `signal(SIGCHLD, ...)` nor `sigaction(SIGCHLD,...)`, and we can infer that the process starts with SIGCHLD set to SIG_DFL.

Comment: Right, but there is still a *default* state of `SIGCHLD` handling; that might be *'as handled by `signal()`'*. In my case life was more complicated (linking with libxl which does its own forks and signal handling if you want the gory details), but I can only say that the above incantation fixed things. Given explicitly setting signal handling is not a bad idea anyway (particularly given the default for `SIGCHLD` is somewhat opaque), I think this is worth OP trying. It might be nothing to do with what I've suggested, in which case the OP merely gets a cleaner signal setup.

Comment: We might be headed into chat territory here, but the default SIGCHLD disposition is well-specified, even on those older systems where `signal()` behaved like SA_RESETHAND.  This answer is a fine technical exposition, but it's not an answer to the question asked.